# Supervisord Celery Haystack Python path

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, supervisord

So I have a Celery task which does some PDF processing and then update the index of my haystack. it is controlled by supervisor

```
command = [
    'python', 'manage.py', 'update_index', 'publications',
    '--batch-size=100', '--age=12'
]
update_haystack_index = subprocess.call(command)
```

my supervisor conf is like this:

```
[program:look-celery]
command=/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/blook/bin/python /vagrant/manage.py celeryd -l info -E --pidfile=/var/lock/look_celery.pid
directory=/vagrant/
user=vagrant
numprocs=1 
stdout_logfile=/var/log/look-celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/look-celeryd.log
autostart=false
autorestart=true 
startsecs=10 
stopwaitsecs=30
```

I am having problems with the Python call because in my update_index subprocess call I am not specifying the Python path the way I am in my supervisor conf and I get a `ImportError: No module named django.core.management` for example.

my workaround was to:

```
PYTHON_ENV = '/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/look/bin/python'
MANAGE_ENV = '/vagrant/manage.py'
command = [
    settings.PYTHON_ENV, settings.MANAGE_ENV, 'update_index',
    'publications', '--batch-size=100', '--age=12'
]
```

I am pretty sure there is a better solution, how can I solve this?